# Qt5 QFileDialog closes parent dialog as well

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dialog, qt5

I have a custom QDialog with a 'Save' button which is supposed to prompt the user with a QFileDialog and save the contents of a Table Widget to a file, but keep the dialog open.

This is the function that opens the dialog and saves the data:

```
bool ResultsDialog::saveData()
{
    QString outfile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save results"), tr(""), tr("CSV Files (*.csv)") );
    if (outfile.isNull() || outfile.isEmpty() )
        return false;
    if (!CSVIO::write_to_csv(*ui->tableWidget, outfile) )
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Failed to save...", QString("Could not save file: %1").arg(outfile) );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the code in for the Save button slot:

```
void ResultsDialog::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    if (saveData() )
    {
        saved = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the code that creates and opens the ResultsDialog:

```
void MainWindow::displayResults()
{
    ResultsDialog *resultsDialog = new ResultsDialog(this);
    resultsDialog->setWindowTitle(windowTitle() );
    resultsDialog->setWindowIcon(windowIcon() );

    connect(resultsDialog, &ResultsDialog::finished, this, &MainWindow::close);

    resultsDialog->fill(playlistTable, notes);
    resultsDialog->setModal(true);
    resultsDialog->open();
    this->hide();
}
```

The problem is, as soon as the QFileDialog is closed, my QDialog is closed along with it, and the following message is printed on the console:

> qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 13049,
> resource id: 25205189, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0 
> 11:59:01: /home/user1/workspace/build-App-Desktop-Debug/App exited
> with code 0

Note that the MainWindow, which is the parent of my custom dialog is hidden. When it's not hidden, this problem goes away, but that's not an option as I want the MainWindow to be hidden.

I am using Qt 5.15 on Debian Bullseye.

Comment: Just checking if I understand well: So if your MainWindow is not hidden, then your ResultsDialog is not automatically closed after QFileDialog gets closed?

Comment: That is correct. I'm adding the code that opens the ResultsDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hooking the termination of the MainWindow to a signal that is sent out while ResultsDialog is still processing. ResultsDialog has MainWindow as its parent so the parent (and its children!!) are destroyed while the child is still running. Nothing good will arise from this construct.

Edit: The Error message you see is not the source of the issue but just an indication that a window was closed suddenly. Which is exactly what you describe.

Edit 2: See the comment section for a workaround (passing 0 as parent to the dialog) and some guessing why the workaround works.

Comment: This may or may not be a problem, but it's not **the** problem here. I haven't had any other issues with this construct. The application is supposed to exit when the ResultsDialog is closed. There is something the QFileDialog is doing that is triggering ResultsDialog to close before it's supposed to, and I can't find out what it is - that's the problem.

Comment: I missed the point what was closed intentionally and what closed magically indeed. There is something obscure going on here: can you open the ResultsDialog with exex() instead of open() to make it a proper application modal dialog (you might have to invert the hide and exec call for this)? What happens if you break the parent hierarchy and pass 0 in the Constructor of ResultsDialog and getSaveFileName?

Comment: I could've sworn I tried passing 0 as the parent for ResultsDialog, but it seems to have done the trick now. At least on Linux - since the app needs to work on Mac and Windows too, I'll test on them too. Passing 0 to getSaveFileName didn't have any effect.

Changing between exec() and open() also makes no difference.

Comment: I guess, that some internal tries to access the size of the toolbar of the MainWindow which probably gives 0 when hidden and that some element tries to make use of this 0 in a division. The access chain to the hidden bar is broken by passing 0.

Comment: That's good to know... I've noticed an interesting behaviour with this bug: I overrode reject() for ResultsDialog to display a QMessageBox should the user try to close without having saved the data, and when QFileDialog is cancelled, it triggers that function and the message box keeps the app alive - although the app still dies when the message box closes even if the `Go Back` button was clicked.

I can confirm that this workaround works on macOS and Windows, so I'll be accepting your answer.